# jqgrid's dates only setting to 1999-11-30 00:00:00

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm displaying a table that holds DATETIME values. Although the values are displaying correctly, once the datetime value has been edited, it automatically transforms to the "1999-11-30 00:00:00" date, both in jqgrid and in the database, no matter what date was written.

```
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: -1 in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3922, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3980, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3980, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3980, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3980, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3980, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3980, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: F in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3981, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: M in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3982, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: n in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3984, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: j in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3986, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: o in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3988, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: y in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3989, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: l in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3990, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: D in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3991, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: N in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3992, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: w in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3993, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: month in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3994, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: day in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3994, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: year in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3994, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: G in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3996, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: h in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3997, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: g in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3998, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: O in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 3999, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Z in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 4000, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: year in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 4006, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: month in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 4007, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: day in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 4008, referer:--------------------users.php
[Tue Mar 12 11:39:28 2013] [error] [client 171.43.1.4] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: hour in /var/www/html/testing/tables/php/jqGrid.php on line 4010, referer:--------------------users.php
```

What could be causing such a problem?

I am not using the datepicker add-on (or any other addons) for jqgrid.

I tried to manually update the values in the database using ajax when the submit button event is fired

```
$grid->setNavEvent('edit', 'onclickSubmit', $updateDate);
```

But it seems the manual update is being overridden by the jqgrid update.

What could be causing the faulty date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$grid->setUserTime("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Cheers.